# Jump at fixed height on single touch : Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make replica of stack jump game for learning. I am trying to make my player jump for fixed height but with below code, it always jumps at different height. If i touch for long then it jumps high and if i touch and release release immediately then it jumps very low. I want my player to jump constant height for long touch or for short touch both. I have just started learning unity. Please help!

Here is my code -

```
 Touch touch;
 if (Input.touchCount > 0)
 {
     touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
     if ((touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) && isGrounded)
     {
          //rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
         rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
         isGrounded = false;
     }
     if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
     {
         //rb.velocity = Vector2.down * jumpForce;
         rb.AddForce(Vector2.down * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
         isGrounded = true;
     }
   }
```

Comment: Is this code inside of your `Update()` method? If it is, it is checking for touch every frame and doing exactly what you say. Keep your `GetTouch(0)` check in `Update()` method and move your jumping logic to a coroutine.

Comment: @Eliasar This code is in FixedUpdate() method. I have just started learning unity from last two day. I am not sure what coroutine is. I will try to implement your suggestion. Thank You! :)

Comment: [Unity3d's Manual on Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and their [Video Tutorial on Coroutines](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/coroutines)

Comment: You are setting isGrounded = true when touch ended.  You should use floor collider to do this. Because when you live you finger isgrounded become true without touching floor. this is problem.

Comment: moje_mast_ram is right. You should be using physics to determine when the character is falling down using floor colliders and gravity. You would use a coroutine if you needed extra processing during each frame of your jump.

Answer (score 1):

I had done exactly the same task when I was learning Unity. So what you have to do is to Add Component Rigitbody2D to your game object

```
private Rigidbody2D body;
private float jumpForce = 12.0f;


void Start()
{
   body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

}

void Update()
{
   bool grounded = false;
   // set to true when your gameObject is on the ground
   // Assume Space button is for jump
   if(grounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
   {
       body.AddForce(Vector2.up*jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
   } 
}
```

So the idea is you jump when are are on the ground (you can use Physics2D.OverlapArea to detect collision with the ground), you can control how high you want to jump, and you do that using AddForce.